# Convert NPM project to browser-compatible JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, node-modules

is it possible to convert a fairly small NPM package to a javascript file that I can reference in HTML with a `<script>` tag?

The NPM package that I am trying to do this with is not complex at all and is basically just an API wrapper that I'd like to use, but I don't want to use Node.

Comment: Check out http://browserify.org/, I think that's what you are asking. Allow's you to pack your dependencies and use require modules in the browser.

Comment: Maybe. It depends on the JavaScript inside the package. It might work in browsers unmodified. It might work if you use a tool to convert it. It might depend on Node.js-specific APIs which don't have equivalents in browsers. It might do things (like use a third-party API) which are subject to additional security restrictions (like the Same Origin Policy) in browsers. There's no enough information in your question to tell if the package you want to use could be converted.

Answer (score 1):

NPM is just a build tool, it helps you organise dependencies and much other.

You can manually make the particular *.js files you want from node_modules available for your html file and use them from there.

Answer (score 0):

use Browserify to convert NPM to a single js file and then refer it in your HTML file